# "GeometryHitTestParameters' HitTestParameters are not supported on 'Viewport3DVisual" error from the new SDK?

Tags: pixelsense, hittest, viewport3d

I was part of a team that developed a Surface application during the summer. I was set to do some minor changes to this application now, but got errors that were not present last time the exact same code was ran.

The error message is "GeometryHitTestParameters' HitTestParameters are not supported on 'Viewport3DVisual" and is complaining about some parameter in theVisualTreeHelper. HitTest().

The code is the same, but the working environment is slightly different:

- I could not find the old SDK, so i had to use Surface SDK 1.0 SP1.
- The computer is running Windows 7

I've got the code running by catching all exceptions and ignoring them.
Does anyone know if Surface SDK SP1 could have changed the way 'Viewport3DVisual is used or if the SDK is throwing exceptions not thrown in 1.0?

I would really like to know if masking this exception will make the application run like it used to or if the changes in behavior would turn up later and backfire.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same exception myself. We were unable to resolve it and just shipped with the defect. I'm pretty sure its a bug in the SDK.